# How to get the value of a text-box in MVC easily

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Hey guys I am new to Stackoverflow and new to MVC.
I am Using vb but c# might help too.
I want to get the username from a login form I created.
 I know my code doesn't work but for demonstration purposes I entered it.
How can I get the UserName textbox value in my controller.

My controller

```
Sub Login()
    Dim rvdDB As New RVDDataClassesDataContext
    Dim Employees = From Employee In rvdDB.Employees Where Employee.EmpID = TUserName
End Sub
```

My View page

```
@ModelType RVDLoginMVC.Login
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Login"
End Code

<div id="MainLogin" style="text-align:center">
    <img src="~/Models/rvd_logo.jpg" alt="Rogue Valley Door" />
    <p>Username: <input id="TUserName" name="TUserName" type="text" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input id="TPassword" name="TPassword" type="password" /></p>
    <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Login", "Login")'" />
</div>
```

Comment: Use the built in asp.net membership provider instead of writing your own

Comment: First off, don't hard code your form names and id's like that. Use a model.

Comment: Ok how can I do this can some one help with code. I am completely new here.

Answer (score 1):

Your view declares a model which I'm assuming has the username and password as properties. You should be creating controls that bind to the model properties and then taking an instance of the model in your Login() method.

My VB.NET is pretty rusty so you may have to play with this a bit.

```
Sub Login(viewModel as RVDLoginMVC.Login)
    Dim rvdDB As New RVDDataClassesDataContext
    Dim Employees = From Employee In rvdDB.Employees Where Employee.EmpID = viewModel.Username
End Sub
```

Then in the View do this. This is the C# flavor of the Razor syntax, I've never done a vbhtml so I don't know the VB.NET flavor.

```
<p>Username: @Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.Username )</p>
<p>Password: @Html.PasswordFor( model => model.Password )</p>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Could you give me a code example. Just to get me started. I am new to MVC

Comment: Hey how can I add the properties.

Comment: Meaning the model Username and password @CraigW

Answer (score 0):

You can access textbox value by passing in Controller FormCollection parameter like given below.

```
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection _frmCollection)
{
  string _userName=_frmCollection["TUserName"];
}
```